# Combination of 'one' and 'live' for submit?

Tags: jquery

I know:

```
$('form').one('submit', function (evt) { ... });
```

I know:

```
$('form').live('submit', function (evt) { ... });
```

Does it exists the combination of both?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, `.live()` is deprecated.  Use `.on()` instead.

Comment: In case if you are using older version of jQuery, then simply use `.unbind` inside `.live` or `.delegate` handler which is same as `.one`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delegate the event higher up the DOM tree:

```js
$('#someAncestor').one('submit', 'form', function (evt) { ... });
```

Note that this is only available in jQuery 1.7+. It takes the same form as the `on` method. This works because DOM events tend to bubble up the tree. If you bind the event handler to an ancestor element, it will eventually reach it. The 2nd argument is a selector. When the event reaches the ancestor, the target is checked against the selector. If it matches, the handler is executed.

Comment: Good answer, seems not everybody realises the one() function was upgraded with on() to delegation as well.

Comment: @adeneo sure but I'd say a more common, if not only, use case for delegated one is where it works like normal one but delegated. This will remove the listener as soon as any form under the ancestor is submitted, not one per form.

Comment: @Esailija - You are right, it will remove the handler on any submit of a form element, but that seems to be the OP's question ?

Comment: @adeneo apparently since it got accepted (or he didn't test it well enough). Something like a combination of `live` and `one` is not what this does (have all current and future forms in the page to have a one-time submit event), even if adapted to `document` selector. But whatever.

Comment: @Esailija - The OPs example of `one` would behave the same way (one form would submit, the handler would unbind). I assumed that's what they wanted.

Comment: @JamesAllardice It would not behave the same way, with `$("form").one` each form would have their one-time submit handler. While in this case any one form being submitted would remove the handlers from others. A non-delegated version of what this does can be demonstrated with `$("form").one( "n.submit", function(){
 $("form").off("n.submit");
});`.

Comment: @Esailija - Oh, sorry yeah I see what you mean. Well, as you said, the OP has accepted. I'm assuming that means they have only one form. It will work fine for that situation.

Comment: Yes, I only have one form. Thanks guys for your help.